# can two machines be used for hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing, namenode

I want to use one machine as a namenode, another machine as a datanode. After configuration, I can find datanode by using "jps" command. But I cant find the datanode when using "hdfs dfsadmin -report" on any of these two machines. So what's wrong? Can two machines not be used for hadoop cluster, and at lease 3 machines?

Comment: yes you can, check if data nodes daemons are working correctly or not! you can run all the master services on machine 1 and all the rest services on machine 2

Comment: You could also have both be datanodes. But you will always need at least one namenode